# Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Error

Tags: active-directory, office365, adal, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I am using Office 365 DLL's to integrate my application with Office 365 Calendars.
Everything working fine until yesterday and stopped working since morning and I have not changed any code or settings.

The exception I am getting is

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Information: 2 : 6/21/2016 5:56:50 AM:  - TokenCache: Deserialized 3 items to token cache.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Information: 2 : 6/21/2016 5:56:54 AM:  - TokenCache: Deserialized 3 items to token cache.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Information: 2 : 6/21/2016 5:56:54 AM:  - AuthenticationContext: ADAL .NET with assembly version '2.23.0.0', file version '2.23.30226.1847' and informational version '0b5f258db72d0632d3693d262acbf77b634e9136' is running...
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Information: 2 : 6/21/2016 5:56:54 AM: 27e2cb5e-d44a-4XX0-bXX6-388XXXXXXXXd7 - AcquireTokenHandlerBase: === Token Acquisition started:
    Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/1XXXXd7f-0c29-4XX9-9XX4-f13825XXXX46/
    Resource: https://api.office.com/discovery/
    ClientId: 6fXXXX63-6XX9-4XX4-9XX9-0eXXXXf1a629
    CacheType: Office365TokenCacheBL (3 items)
    Authentication Target: UserPlusClient

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Information: 2 : 6/21/2016 5:56:56 AM:  - TokenCache: Deserialized 3 items to token cache.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Verbose: 1 : 6/21/2016 5:56:56 AM: 27XXXX5e-dXXa-4XX0-bXX6-38XXXX2d9ad7 - TokenCache: Looking up cache for a token...
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Information: 2 : 6/21/2016 5:56:56 AM: 27XXXX5e-dXXa-4XX0-bXX6-388XXXX9ad7 - TokenCache: An item matching the requested resource was found in the cache
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Verbose: 1 : 6/21/2016 5:56:56 AM: 27XXXX5e-dXXa-4XX0-bXX6-38XXXX2d9ad7 - TokenCache: 52.1731331333333 minutes left until token in cache expires
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Information: 2 : 6/21/2016 5:56:56 AM: 27XXXX5e-dXXa-4XX0-bXX6-38XXXX2d9ad7 - TokenCache: A matching item (access token or refresh token or both) was found in the cache
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Information: 2 : 6/21/2016 5:56:56 AM: 27XXXX5e-dXXa-4XX0-bXX6-38XXXX2d9ad7 - AcquireTokenHandlerBase: === Token Acquisition finished successfully. An access token was retuned:
    Access Token Hash: mU0K9hd7I9oZs2xNXXXXXXXVTyQY6IoBc636dUAIH0=
    Refresh Token Hash: 1pq0a2MeN/pMOn0VXXXXXXX2APDqUIDgIaEOcjJWp8=
    Expiration Time: 6/21/2016 6:49:06 AM +00:00
    User Hash: LEIVCDzkEaYHwWq9kXXXXXXg0SHrVOQs4EELpUPBLaE=

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Error: 4 : 6/21/2016 5:58:02 AM: dde01a1c-75a3-4511-8bfa-bccc4193b06a - <<CreateOffice365Service>b__1>d__14: Microsoft.Office365.Discovery.DiscoveryFailedException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Office365.Discovery.DiscoveryFailedException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.Office365.Discovery.DiscoveryClient.<DiscoverServicesAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Office365.Discovery.DiscoveryClient.<DiscoverCapabilitiesAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Office365.Discovery.DiscoveryClient.<DiscoverCapabilityAsync>d__1a.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Office365CalendarProviderBL.<>c__DisplayClass4.<<CreateOffice365Service>b__1>d__14.MoveNext() in d:\path.cs line no.-x
```

Please suggest where I can look for the issue in code or if anything else needed here

Comment: Off-hand I'd say make sure your DLLs are up to date with the latest versions on NuGet. If they are, you should post the relevant code so we have a better idea of what's going on here.